# Customer Schedulling & route optimization

Tags: optimization, scheduling, or-tools

I'm new to ORTools and I need some guidance on which algorithm to choose for this problem:
(I think it is an assignment problem, but also a mix with route optimization and VRP..)

1. A salesman has N shops to visit
2. Every shop has a service time T (ex: 30 minutes)
3. Shops are categorized this way:

- a) Category 1 = must be visited twice a week
- b) Category 2 = must be visited once a week
- c) Category 3 = must be visited biweekly (every two weeks)
- d) Category 4 = must be visited once a month

4. A shop cant be visited 2 days in a row
5. The salesman should work up to 9 hours (1 hour for lunch)
6. The salesman should visit 8 to 12 shops a day (soft constraint)
7. The salesman should work up to 176 hours a month
8. Some shops can be discarded from the solution. (prefer to keep the ones with lower category)
9. We have the geolocation and a time distance matrix for the shops

The objectives are:

- Maximize the number of shop visited
- Minimize the KMs for the salesman

*This is an example of shops distribution*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like you're trying to solve the problem globally, i.e. to find an optimal monthly or yearly schedule for the entire problem. I suspect that might be difficult, and suggest to try relaxing the problem, say: to a daily one.

For instance, maybe for a given day, it's possible to compile a list of stores which should be visited, perhaps by order of scores. So maybe a store that was visited yesterday will not be in the list; and one that has to be visited once a week, and was visited 6 days ago would be on the top of the list.

Then, you might be able to solve using a variant of the VRP solver on that list; you can use simulation (maybe with some random element) to generate a weekly or monthly schedule based on that. It's not guaranteed to be optimal, but might be good enough.

If your problem is more complex then what the OR-Tools VRP solver can handle, you can try using the more general CP-SAT solver, which is very generic, and can handle VRP-like problems with additional constraints, e.g. Scheduling problems or other constraints.

You can also consider using other approaches here, e.g. Tabu search.

Comment: Thanks @etov good aproach. I've found this paper that tries to solve the problem as a LP problem in different stages using an heuristic approach 
[A Model and Solution Method for Solving the Real-world and Complex Problem of Scheduling Visits to Customers](http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/jart/v12n3/v12n3a1.pdf)